# Mock a method within another method in mockmvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

I'm new to MockMVC and junit stuffs so need a help ,so the situation is I need to mock a method while mocking the outer method which contains the method. For example method calculator(int a , int b) , i mock this method with two mock values, and within this method there is another method which does some other validations (lets say some external validations) .

I'm able to mock the main method calculator till the point where this external method is being called, i used to "Given().willReturn()" to mock the main method (calculator), and another "Given().willReturn()" statement to mock the containing method(validations one), but that gives me nullPointer exception. So I need something that could help me with this, so that the mocking can be done in an orderly fashion.

```
     public GuestRegistrationResponse registerGuest(SomeObject guestRegistrationRequest) throws Exception {

    SomeObject guestRegistrationResponse = new SomeObject();
    Folio folio = new Folio();

    folio.setForename(guestRegistrationRequest.getForename());
    folio.setEmail1(guestRegistrationRequest.getEmail());
    folio.setCity(guestRegistrationRequest.getCity());


    Result result = null;
    result = (Result) sampleAPICall.executeExternalAPI(result,new Class[] { SomeObject.class, User.class, Another.class, Folio.class, FolioList.class },
            Result.class);
    if (result != null && result.getFolioList() != null ) {
        guestRegistrationResponse.setFolioid(result.getFolioList().getFolio().getFolioId());

    } else {
        throw new ExternalException(result.getResult());
    }
    return guestRegistrationResponse;
}
```

**Test method**

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @WebMvcTest(value = ServiceImpl.class, secure = true)
 public class TestServiceImpl {

@Autowired
MockMvc mockmvc;

@InjectMocks
ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // We would need this line if we would not use MockitoJUnitRunner
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // Initializes the JacksonTester
    JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
}

@Test
public void testRegisterGuest() throws Exception {

        SomeObject mockInput = new SomeObject();

        mockInput.setCity("CITY");
            mockInput.setEmail("test@test.com");
    mockInput.setForename("FORENAME");
    /* other datat is also collected*/
    ExpectedResponse mockOutput = new ExpectedResponse();
    mockOutput.setResult(true);

    Result Result = new Result();
    Result.setMessage("success");
    Result.setStatus(true);
    processTestThatMethod(mockInput, mockOutput,  Result);
}

private void processTestThatMethod(SomeObject mockInput, ExpectedResponse mockOutput,
         ,Result result) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside processTestThatMethod");
     given(serviceImpl.registerGuest(mockInput)).willReturn(mockOutput);
         // what to do below ..
             given(sampleAPICall.executeExternalAPI(any(Result.class),any(new Class[]{SomeObject.class, User.class, Another.class, Folio.class, FolioList.class}),any(Result.class))).willReturn(result);

}
}
```

Have edited the code @Sachin rai

Comment: at least put some effort to format code before you post it

Comment: I'm sorry Deadpool , its not a proper code it's just some example to show the logic, That's why added it as a statement . Thanks for the downVote.

Comment: nope i'm not the downvote @david

Comment: just kidding @Pool , and whoever downvoted please do answer my query , at least a  small clue or links could help my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Mock
    private class object;
    @Test
     public void testCalculator() {

      given(object.calculator(2,3)).willreturn(1);
      // remove the following line as when validate method will be called it will itself return true assuming it has simple check for positive value a and not calling any other method inside it
      given(class.validate(2)).willReturn(true); 
      //asserts here //
      }
```

Comment: hey , I tried this approach but the thing is while the first "given" statement gets executed it covers up the "calculator()" method right before " if(big.getResult()!=true) { " and it gives Nullpointer exception because the variable big is actually null !! So in a way my second "given" statement doesn't get a chance to get involved.

Comment: can u show your `validate(a)` method ? if your `validate` method is returning an instance of `big` setting its `Result` value as `true` or `false ` then `big.getResult()` will not throw Null pointer exception.

Comment: Hey sachin , the validate(a) method returns an object of "Result" which has 'result' and 'status' as getters/setters within it.

Comment: have edited the code , if you find anything missing , please expect it to be present in the code, as the code is really lengthy and have cut short it to make some sense/logic .@sachin

Comment: NB: the second given doesn't get a chance to get executed as the first invokes the method and gets stuck at the if condition in the Service.

Comment: @david, the  code is likely to give you Null Pointer Exception  in else part since result will be null at this line:                                                                                   `if (result != null && result.getFolioList() != null ) {
        guestRegistrationResponse.setFolioid(result.getFolioList().getFolio().getFolioId());

    } else {
        throw new ExternalException(result.getResult());  //NPE here, since result is null above
    }`

Comment: exactly @sachin , so what am i supposed to do , to mock that particular code in my first given statement ??

Comment: `if(result!=null)
    {
        if (result.getFolioList() != null) {
            guestRegistrationResponse.setFolioid(result.getFolioList().getFolio().getFolioId());
        } else if (result.getResult() != null) {
            throw new ExternalException(result.getResult());
        }
    }else {
        throw new ExternalException("ANY CUSTOM EXCEPTION MESSAGE");
    }`

Comment: `processTestThatMethod` name must be `processTestRegisterGuest` as I guess same method is being called here. shouldn't be ? correct me.

Comment: Yes both are the same @sachin  : )

Comment: also you need to mock `sampleAPICall`  instance like  `@Mock SampleAPICall sampleAPICall;`  near to where `@InjectMocks` is declared. pls start app in debug mode and verify line by line whether still any instance is  null. let me know if you still face any prob.

Comment: hey @sachin I have mocked `sampleAPICall` instance like `@Mock SampleAPICall sampleAPICall;`  defined in my actual code , and debug is also done , so the thing is right before  `result = (Result) sampleAPICall.executeExternalAPI(result,new Class[] { SomeObject.class, User.class, Another.class, Folio.class, FolioList.class },
            Result.class);` this i have initialised the object as `Result result = null;` . but I have no option to make change the code ,I need to manage it within the Mock class.

Comment: setting null is not a good idea anyway. you can safely set this line as `Result Result = new Result();` in `registerGuest` method instead of null. On the other hand in your `testRegisterGuest` method you can remove this same line from there and instead mock it in the same way like done for `SampleAPICall` i e. `@Mock Result result;`

Comment: Even if I set the line as `Result Result = new Result();` in `registerGuest` method instead of null , It wont help me , Because `result != null && result.getFolioList() != null` the second condition should also be satisfied.

Comment: `@Mock
private Result result;      
@Mock
FolioList folioList;         
@Mock
Folio folio;     

@Before   
public void setUp() {  
    //othercode  ...  .                                                                          
  folio.setId(1);   
 folioList.setFolio(folio);   
}     

@Test
public void testRegisterGuest() throws Exception {
     //other code                                         
    
 
    result.setMessage("success");   
    result.setStatus(true);     
 result.setFolioList(folioList);     
 processTestThatMethod(mockInput, mockOutput,  result); `

Comment: remove `result != null` condition from `if (result != null && result.getFolioList() != null )`
    now when `sampleAPICall.executeExternalAPI` is called it will retun your mocked and earlier set `result` instance so that when `result.getFolioList().getFolio().getFolioId()` is called it will return 1

Comment: I'm afraid , I cant do that mate , that `result != null` is there for a reason. And if you remember the 2nd `given` statement doesn't get executed. @sachin , I am getting the error on the first Statement itself..!!!

Comment: ok got it then leave `Result result = null;`  it doesnt matter since you have dictated that `sampleAPICall.executeExternalAPI(any(Result.class),any(new Class[]{SomeObject.class, User.class, Another.class, Folio.class, FolioList.class}),any(Result.class))).willReturn(result);`    your null result will be replaced by your mocked instance. but atleast you should at least set  `result.setResult(someResultInstance)` so that when `result.getResult()` is called it does not throw Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: pls run your code on debug mode and find the line where any method is being called on a null object;